# Какое правило объясняет написание названия магии с большой буквы?

Tags: морфология

В художественной литературе названия заклинаний, названия видов магии, названия магических знаков пишут с заглавной буквы. Какое правило применяется в таком случае?

Примеры:

1. Ведьмачьи Знаки (Знак Аксий): «Ривянин выпрямился. Быстро перехватил меч под левую руку, а правой, выставив её в сторону стражников, начертил в воздухе сложный Знак».
2. «Он использовал заклинание Огненного шара».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Это обычное правило, связанное **со структурой составного имени собственного**, его можно вывести из Правил Розенталя и применять к каждой **конкретной тематике**. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=13#pp13

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** ПЕРЕД ИМЕНЕМ СОБСТВЕННЫМ. Перед именем собственным может находиться родовое наименование в роли приложения – написание со строчной буквы.

**ПРОПИСНАЯ БУКВА**. С прописной буквы пишутся следующие слова в составе имени собственного: (1) первое слово; (2) слова с индивидуальным, или условным,  значением имени; (3) слова особой важности; (4) другие имена собственные, входящие в данное составное имя.

**СТРОЧНАЯ БУКВА**. Со строчной буквы пишутся следующие слова в составе имени собственного: (1) родовые наименования; (2) другие слова с реальным, а не условным значением; (3) служебные слова.

2. Слово ***ЗНАК*** в данном случае является именем собственным и пишется с прописной буквы ввиду особого смысла, который в него вложен. Он может быть одиночным именем (Знак), а может входит в составные имена: ***Знак Аксий, Ведьмачьи Знаки***.

А вот *заклинание* – это приложение, стоящее перед составным именем: ***заклинание Огненного шара.*** В этом составном имени только первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, а второе слово (шар) имеет не условное, а реальное значение (строчная буква).