# Как пишутся названия уникальных игровых предметов?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, существительные

Разговор зашёл о том, как писать собственные названия уникальных предметов в видеоиграх. Только 1 слово с прописной, все слова с прописной или вообще в кавычках? Например: Кольцо морозной стужи, Поножи учёного, Рубашка бесстыдного обманщика... А если название предмета не содержит родового слова: кольцо Тень Смерти, сапоги Длань Господа — тогда как писать? Единственный ориентир нашли в литературе — названия мечей, которые пишутся прописными (меч Вдовий Плач, клинок Губитель Сердец в "Игре престолов"). Так как же быть?

Comment: Я задавал похожий вопрос (только с другим примером). Ответ на него дала Sharon: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/471204/200257

Answer (score 2):

Речь не просто о названиях "уникальных предметов" - это их имена собственные.

Всё по правилам, забудьте о кавычках:

Кольцо морозной стужи, Поножи учёного, Рубашка бесстыдного обманщика (ога, увидела допустимый вариант - каждое слово с прописной, но не настаиваю),

меч Вдовий Плач, клинок Губитель Сердец, кольцо Тень Смерти, сапоги Длань Господа (здесь также второе слово могло бы быть со строчной за исключениям Господа - по своим причинам).

Родовое слово может предполагать или даже предлагать кавычки, но не обязательно и на прописные-строчные не влияет.